# Резиновые блоки

Tags: html, css

Доброго всем времени суток, есть вот такой код http://jsfiddle.net/AJIEKCEU/n8Hf2/
как сделать так чтобы при уменьшении разрешения экрана, блок small_img не съезжал?, а сами картинки исходя из размера экрана съезжали. то-есть если уменьшить окно браузера к примеру, сам блок едет вниз а должно быть так чтобы картинки ехали одна под одну, а блок всегда был слева.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

А табличное представление на что?

Я бы так как-то сверстал: http://jsfiddle.net/WDQBz/1/

Comment: Супер, это я и хотел +1

Answer (score 0):

У тебя там все стоит в одном div'е. Разделяй их. 1 div давай big_img, а 1 div давай small_img. И постарайся писать внятный код. Я хотел сразу код тебе скинуть, но не разобрался какой класс там к чему. Зачем тебе задавать стиль и в CSS и внутри блока DIV??? Избавься от этой привычки. Пиши все в CSS файле. Это один из правил писании кода.
Перезапиши код свой как я сказал, потом скинь сюда и я помогу тебе.

Comment: да css тут просто для примера написан, я код с сайта копирнул, сайт не мой))а код счас перепишу если этот глаза режит))

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/AJIEKCEU/n8Hf2/ вот

Answer (score 0):

Может чего не понял, но посмотрите [такой вариант](http://jsfiddle.net/Deonis/n8Hf2/3/). И в следующий раз, выкладывайте код с изображениями, если таковые имеют место быть, плиззз.

Для проверки работоспособности, манипулируйте размерами фреймов:
[image]